# REST API from PowerShell - "POST Method not allowed"

Tags: powershell, api, rest, bitbucket, invoke-restmethod

I am trying to upload one file to BitBucket repository (Git system).
I am trying to send that using the REST API but the error Indicates that POST method is not allowed, although I can of course using the "git push" command to send new files. But if I try to POST the file I am getting this error: **"HTTP Status 405 – Method Not AllowedType Status ReportMessage Request method POST not supported"**

I am trying to that with this code:

```
$API_KEY="NDU2"
$uri="https://bitbucket.dev/projects/TEST/repos/faselect/browse/test"
$jsonFile=Get-Content -Raw -Pat C:\Users\john\Downloads\test1.json
Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri  -Headers @{Authorization="$("Basic {0}" -f $API_KEY)"} -Method Post -Body $jsonFile -ContentType 'application/json'
```

Answer (score 0):

My approach to this would be to look on PowerShell gallery [Powerhell Gallery](https://www.powershellgallery.com/packages?q=bitbucket) and see if you can find what you are looking for as a start.. there are several projects that are using this rest api that you could use as an example.  here is one that I found on one of those projects:
[Ps-bitbucket in Github](https://github.com/i9shankar/ps-bitbucket/blob/88edaf469014da16179bb7b215f3fbad04bf2373/Private/Invoke-BitBucketWebRequest.ps1)

Comment: Hi @thom schumacher

Comment: Hi @thom schumacher. Thanks for given example:
It seems very similar to me their example.They put:
`Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "$ResourceUrl" -Method $Method -Headers $Headers -UseBasicParsing -ContentType $ContentType -Body $Body`

and that what I try (I was just missing this UseBasicParsing but I added that, and I am using Invoke-RestMethod instead of Invoke-WebRequest but it should be the same, but same error..
Can you help me?
`Invoke-RestMethod -Uri $uri  -Headers @{Authorization="$("Basic {0}" -f $API_KEY)"} -UseBasicParsing -Method Post -Body $jsonFile -ContentType 'application/json'`